# spring boot cxf soap ws-modify namespace

Tags: spring-boot, soap, cxf, transformation, xml-namespaces

I am working on spring boot soap-ws project with contract last approach using CXF. I have xml request from a client as below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <teen xmlns="some url">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
         //DATA
          </arg0>
      </teen>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The service is not accepting the above request. I would like to change the xml request to below(service accepts below message). The arg0 should have an added empty namespace.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:se>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <teen xmlns="some url">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0 xmlns="">
         //DATA
          </arg0>
      </teen>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can someone help me on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and here is the answer. I have created a below class and implemented the handlemethod of extended class. The handlemethod does all the xml modification.

```
public class InvalidCharInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    
    public InvalidCharInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE); // This is important which determines at what point are we modifying the xml.
    }
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

}
}
```

And, then I added the new interceptor class in my webserviceconfig class.

```
EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, "service-class-name");
endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new InvalidCharInterceptor());
```

FYI..Apache cxf has detailed explanation on interceptors. https://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html